# storing heterogeneous json objects in same MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, json, perl

What is the recommended way of storing heterogeneous json strings into the same MySQL table?
I've got some other tables in this MySQL database that store information other than JSON objects, so I would like to store these JSON objects in this same DB in the best recommended way.

I want to store json strings from a Perl script into a MySQL table that not only won't have the same values, but also will have different hierarchical structures in the different json objects. I am considering storing them as either strings or blobs, together with some minimal metadata for each entry. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `entry` (
  `entry_id`               int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file`                   varchar(1023)    DEFAULT NULL,
  `json`                   blob             DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_timestamp`       TIMESTAMP        DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Are there any tools or libraries I should consider before I do this straight on with Perl and MySQL? I wonder if there is anything out there that does the reverse of what DBIx::JSON does for SELECT queries from MySQL...

Comment: You should consider some non-relational database instead (they mostly operate on key-value pair concept) rather than using a blob.

Comment: @DVK  I've got some other tables in this MySQL database that store information other than JSON objects, so I would like to store these JSON objects in this same DB in the best recommended way.

Comment: You might want to think about implementing some sort of ORM for at least part of the data you've serialized as JSON; as Karoly points out in his answer, this will work just fine unless you want to be able to query across the serialized data, in which case you're going to be pretty much out of luck.

Comment: it sounds like you need some NoSQL, check out Redis, using a hash might be what you need, otherwise storing a json blob is going to make things slow since you can't query the data inside of it.

Comment: I found that Postgresql 9.3 has better capabilities for JSON than the MySQL versions I am using: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17805483/719016

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that Postgresql 9.3 has better capabilities for JSON than the MySQL versions I am using:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#JSON%3a_Additional_functionality

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 5):

Json objects in the DB are perfectly fine until you don't want to query the content of it.

The storage type however is worth the discussion. I would compress either the whole ROW in InnoDB with ( ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8 ) or doing it in the application compressing only the JSON and put it in binary format.

With the first option (application handles TEXT, MySQL handles compression) I would prefer the json column to by text type (TEXT, LONGTEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, TINYTEXT).

With the second version (application handles compression, MySQL only sees binary) I would of course use blob format (TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB).

Both are valid options. It really depends on your personal priorities. Moving compression to application is the benefit of scaling easier but introduce complexity. Let MySQL take care of compression is transparent and easy to setup however it puts some pressure on CPU (which is by the way rarely a bottleneck for databases).